# Why does method return 0?

Tags: javascript, object, methods

Using the object and methods below, why does `console.log(FizzBuzzPlus.getFizzBuzzCount(20))` print 0?

```
var FizzBuzzPlus = {
    isFizzBuzzie: function(a) {
        if(a%5 === 0 || a%3 === 0) {
            if (a%5 === 0 && a%3 === 0) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    },

    isFizzBuzzieChecker: function(c) {
        var theFizzBuzzes = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            if (this.isFizzBuzzie(i)) {
                theFizzBuzzes += i + " ";
            }
        }
        return theFizzBuzzes;
    },

    getFizzBuzzSum: function(b) {
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < b; i++) {
            if (this.isFizzBuzzie(i)) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    },

    getFizzBuzzCount: function(c) {
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            if (this.isFizzBuzzie(i)) {
                count++;
            }
        return count;
        }
    }
};

console.log(FizzBuzzPlus.isFizzBuzzieChecker(20));
console.log(FizzBuzzPlus.getFizzBuzzSum(20));
console.log(FizzBuzzPlus.getFizzBuzzCount(20));
```

Some may recognize that this is FizzBuzz from Codecademy. I'm playing with the object using their online JavaScript editor. The printed result of the method is always 0. It should be returning the amount of numbers between 0 and 20 that are divisible by 3 or 5, but not both 3 and 5.

Comment: Thanks. Syntax error was a typo not in original code. Moved return statement. Now works correctly.

Comment: You should probably fix up the typo in your question then ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point in your code you have your `return` statement inside your `for` loop:

```
getFizzBuzzCount: function(c) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        if (this.isFizzBuzzie(i)) {
            count++;
        }
    return count; //<-- this return is INSIDE the for loop
    }
}
```

Move that `return` outside the `for` loop:

```
getFizzBuzzCount: function(c) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        if (this.isFizzBuzzie(i)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count; 
}
```

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/hVf9n/

Answer (score 0):

You have the return statement inside the for loop, also there is a syntax error in `isFizzBuzzieChecker`, where the closing `)` is missing in the `if` condition

```
getFizzBuzzCount: function(c) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        if (this.isFizzBuzzie(i)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/R9jZ4/)